# Clear float last li element for ie6 and 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have following html for menu

```
<ul>
    <li id="btnHome"><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
    <li id="btnAbout"><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
    <li id="btnContact"><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
    <li id="btnLinks"><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

and following is my css for it

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav {
    background: #999;
    padding: 2%;
}

#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

I use above for IE6 and 7 in order to display links in a single row. `float: left` displays menu items in a row but it also changes the style for `#nav` div and menu items do not appear inside `#nav` div anymore.

**How can I fix this issue for IE6 and 7?**

Note: I am using `display: inline-block` for modern browser and this works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CSS declaration like `zoom: 1;` for `#nav` element to trigger [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) on IE 6-7.

```css
#nav {
    background: #999;
    padding: 2%;
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

**Note:** The [star/asterisk prefix](http://webstandardstips.com/2008/11/18/css-hacks-for-ie-only-style-rules/) is a CSS hack for targeting IE 6/7.

### Other options

- Using [`overflow: hidden;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for the `#nav` element to create a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/block_formatting_context).
- Creating an element with `clear: both;` CSS declaration as the last child of the `#nav` element.

You might want to take a look at *Nicolas Gallagher's* **[micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure without the rest of the document but you could try adding a

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

right after your close your ul element, that should grow the size of your containing #nav to the place your floated content occupies in it.

Comment: Is there something missing from your answer. I'm struggling to make sense of it?

Comment: It should be ok now, I forgot to put the code in a codeblock so it got stripped out. You should see my answer by refreshing the page. Basically just adding any element at the end of your list with style="clear:both" should fix your issue by making the container grow to the end of your floated elements.